# Is it possible to assign the result of Solve command to the variables?

Tags: equation-solving

I am having a hard time with a huge script. I use `Solve` function to solve my algebraic equation with parameters of the 4 th order. The result is really messy. Is that possible to assign the roots to variables automatically? Now I use `Standartform` function, copy and paste each root separately in a new cell, in order to write the result in a new variables.

If it is not clear what I want, suppose we have an equation we want to solve:

```
In[841]:= StandardForm[Solve[a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, x]]

Out[841]//StandardForm= {{x -> (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(
2 a)}, {x -> (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}}
```

In order to work with 2 roots, I have to write two new lines, and copy\paste the result from `Out[841]`. I want both roots to be written in 2 new variables automatically, so I can work with these variables immidiately.

After doing a quick search through a documentation of `Solve`, I didn't find the answer.

Thanks,

Comment: Look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/29734). And you can always assign the output of `Solve` to a variable `sols`, say, and then do `x /. First@sols`.

Comment: Caution: StandardForm, MatrixForm, NumberForm, (basically all the *Forms) make something pretty to look at AND at the same time make it inconvenient or impossible to then do any further calculations with that. This is a mistake that new users and the obsessive desktop publishers make over and over. If you do myvar=Solve[...] and then Print[StandardForm[myvar]] then you can usually avoid this problem.

Comment: oh, I see, thanks. Should I close the problem?